# How to join streams cross ksqlDB clusters?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

## How to join streams cross ksqlDB clusters?

Suppose, I have stream in 3 difference ksqlDB hosted on Confluent Cloud

- In `ksqlDB_A` has `stream_A`
- In `ksqlDB_B` has `stream_B`
- In `ksqlDB_C` has `stream_C`
  And I want to join streams A,B,C together on `ksqlDB_C`, how can I achieve that?
  Cuz I cannot see `stream_A` and `stream_B` in `ksqlDB_C` cluster?

Answer (score 0):

ksqlDB clusters/servers are stateless. Kafka is where the topics are stored. If you have separate *Kafka clusters*, then you need to use tools like MirrorMaker2 or Confluent Replicator to mirror the topics into the other clusters that ksqlDB is reading from.